# socket connections closing when manually deploying

Tags: sockets, devops, load-balancing, continuous-deployment

We made a chat module in our project using **socket.io**. When the load is balanced and the manual deployed, if socket connections are switched to different servers, socket connections are disconnected and the messaging events are partially not processed. I solved the load balance problem with **socket.io-redis** library. It acts as a gateway and solves this problem thanks to redis.

Another problem is that when I deploy it manually, the pid of the servers changes and socketio connections are instantly **disconnected** on the client and then it is not connected even though it says connected.

Do you think that using tools such as **Travis CI** solves the problems in manual deploy process?

Another question is, if a system that goes to 3 servers with load balance then goes back to 2 servers, the socket connections will be closed again, what method may be required to solve this? I thought of separating the socket.io service from the monolithic structure and keeping it on a single server, and scaling the server vertically when the load increased.

*We are using an Aws Elastic Beanstalk(EBS), it automatically performs load balance.*